# Countably infinite set and uncountable collection of subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I Prove or disprove that every uncountable collection of subsets of a countably infinite set must have two members whose intersection has at least 2010 elements?

Comment: Hint: How many sets of $2010$ natural numbers are there?

Answer (score 0):

This is true.

Let $A$ be this countable set and let $\binom{A}{2010}$ be the set of subsets of $A$ of size $2010$. Let $F$ be an uncountable collection of subsets of $A$.

Let $f: F\rightarrow P(\binom{A}{2010})$ be the function $f(B)=\binom{B}{2010}$ (sends a subset of $A$ to the set of subsets of size $2010$).
Assume by contrary that $f(B) \cap f(C)=\varnothing$ for every different $B, C\in F$.
Now consider the disjoint union of $f(B)$ for $B\in F$.
There is a countable number of $B$ such that $f(B)=\varnothing$ (**why?**) and therefore the disjoint union is uncountable. But it is a subset of $\binom{A}{2010}$ which is countable, contradiction.